# Phonegap MobileJQuery AJAX Posts Twice while debugging

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Hope there is some out there that can help!, 
While debugging a WCF service that a phonegap application connects to it seems to post twice.

When the application runs normally no Break points etc it all works fine and i only receive 1.
It appears to me that ajax reposts itself if no response is returned from the server after a few seconds.

I will need to confirm this threw wireshark but just wanted to know if anyone else has come accross this before.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ServicePATH ,
                data: JSON.stringify({ objs: arrayobj, parm2: var2, parm3: var3, parm4: 1 }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    CallonSuccess(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('error ' + textStatus);
                    console.log('XMLHttpRequest ' + XMLHttpRequest);
                    var str = '';
                    for (prop in XMLHttpRequest) {
                        str += "prop " + prop + " value :" + XMLHttpRequest[prop] + "\n"; //Concate prop and its value from object
                    }
                    console.log(str);
                    console.log('errorThrown ' + errorThrown);
                    console.log('passing ' + JSON.stringify({ objs: arrayobj, parm2: var2, parm3: var3, parm4: 1 }));
                }
            }).done(function () { console.log('Finished ajax'); });
```

Thanks Lmac

Comment: `function CallonSuccess()` what written inside it?

Comment: Its a for loop which goes threw all the data returned from server if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps no solution (see update below) for you but the same behaviour here.

Without the jquery Mobile framework everything works okay, with the framework embedded it fetches my json file a second time. In Chrome's Console you can see it under Network: GET status 200 and GET status 304 (not modified).

I have the option to throw out jQuery Mobile and I surely will. But would be also interested in knowing what's happening there.

UPDATE: 
I had the xmlhttprequest within the $(document).ready(function() { }); It seems as if both jQuery and jQuery Mobile react to that.

If I put the script at the end of the site and make my xmlhttprequest outside the ready-method it fetches my json file only once.